# What are some of the other viewer of Postgres that folks use?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I've been holding out on upgrading my Postgres installation because I don't want to use the new pgAdmin viewer. What are some of the other alternatives that people like?

Comment: I like Valentina Studio: https://www.valentina-db.com/en/valentina-studio-overview (have been using it on Ubuntu for two or three years now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html), the terminal-based frontend that ships with PostgreSQL. It's quite powerful.

I've written an [extensive guide](https://phili.pe/posts/postgresql-on-the-command-line/) on how to use it, which I hope convinces you of its power.

Comment: Thanks Philipe! but don't you like to see the visual of the tables when you are interacting with them? That's the biggest reason I haven't switched yet.

Comment: `\d tablename` (or `\d+ tablename` for more details) gives me everything I need.

Comment: @Matt, I've fixed the link for the guide I wrote. Make sure to check it out :)